# Boxplot with axis limits in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have data in tab delimited format with nearly 400 columns filled with values ie

```
         X             Y         Z               A       B               C  
        2.34          .89       1.4             .92     9.40            .82
        6.45          .04       2.55            .14     1.55            .04
        1.09          .91       4.19            .16     3.19            .56
        5.87          .70       3.47            .80     2.47            .90
```

Now I want visualize the data using box plot method.Though it is difficult to view 400 in single odf,I want split into 50 each.ie(50 x 8).Here is the code I used:

```
boxplot(data[1:50],xlab="Samples",xlim=c(0.001,70),log="xy", 
        pch='.',col=rainbow(ncol(data[1:50)))
```

but I got the following error:

> In plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs)
>   :   nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,4.4591,2, .); log=1]

I want to view the box plots for 400 samples with 50 each in a 8 different pdf....Please do help me in getting better visualization.

Comment: You are plotting 400 boxes in the same graph?

Comment: Are the columns categorical?  If so why are you using a logarithmic axis?  If not perhaps you should normalise the dataset so that the column-type gets it's own field (as per @Ben's answer) - you'll find it easier to make sense of your columns like that.

Comment: @James Yes I want to plot in the same graph

Comment: @Thileepan I think you'll find it difficult to produce a meaningful graph with so much data on it. You may want to subset your data with to the columns that are of most interest to your application.

Comment: PS a log-y scale makes some sense, but can you explain a bit more your intention in using a logarithmic x axis? (this follows up @RobinGower's question above).  Also, what is `raw.expression` above?  Is it the same as `data`?  Using colours to differentiate categories is a good idea, but if that command comes out to `rainbow(400)` then it will be pretty but not actually be very useful for differentiating the data ... What is the structure of the columns not represented above?  Are they all unique, or do categories A, B, C, X, Y, Z, ... repeat?

Comment: @BenBolker raw.expression is the same data.All the columns are unique.I generally uses the rainbow as it differentiates between each plots but if there is better option for the colors please do suggest me.I take log="y" so that there is some sort of Uniformity along the y axis which useful in visualizing the data in well manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you will have to do something a bit drastic to distinguish 400 boxes in the same graph.  The code below uses two tricks: (1) reverse the usual x-y order so that it's easier to read the labels (plotted on the y axis); (2) send the output to a tall, skinny PDF file so that you can scroll through it at your leisure.  I also opted to sort the variables by mean, to make the plot easier to interpret -- that would be optional, but I suspect you'd have a hard time looking up a particular category in a 400-box plot in any case ...

```
nc <- 400
z <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nc*100),ncol=nc))
library(ggplot2)
m <- melt(z)
m <- transform(m,variable=reorder(variable,value))
pdf(width=10,height=50,file="boxplot.pdf")
print(ggplot(m,aes(x=variable,y=value))+geom_boxplot()+coord_flip())
dev.off()
```

Comment: `melt`!  Where have you been all my r-life?!

Comment: it's in the `reshape` package (which is a dependency of `ggplot2`, so gets loaded automatically)

Comment: @BenBolker I want ot boc plots for the first 50 and then next 50 and thenon..But when I tried using the following code "boxplot(raw.expression[1:50],log="xy",xlim=c(0.001,70),pch='.',col=rainbow(ncol(raw.expression[1:50])))"                               It igves me the following error:"In plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) :
  nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,4.4591,2, .); log=1]" Please help me

Comment: It's hard to help without a *reproducible* example.  Are there zeros or negative values anywhere in your first 50 columns?  I understand why you're using a log-y scale, but still have no idea why you're using a log-x scale too (i.e., I would recommend `log="y"` instead of `log="xy"` unless you have a good reason)

Answer (score 4):

Others have already pointed out that actual boxplots are not going to work well. However, there *is* a very efficient way to visually scan all of your variables: **Simply plot their distributions as an image** (i.e. heatmap). Here is an example showing how it is really quite easy to get the gist of 400 variables and 80,000 individual data points!

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(12345)
n.var = 400
n.obs = 200
data  = matrix(rnorm(n.var*n.obs), nrow=n.obs)

# Summarize data
breaks = seq(min(data), max(data), length.out=51)
histdata = apply(data, 2, function(x) hist(x, plot=F, breaks=breaks)$counts)

# Plot
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
image(1:n.var, breaks, t(histdata), xlab='Variable Index', ylab='Histogram Bin')
```

[image]

This will be most useful if all your variables are comparable, or are at least sorted into rational groups. `hclust` and the `heatmap` functions can also be helpful here for more complicated displays. Good luck!

Comment: I want to make box plots for the first 50 and then next 50 and thenon..But when I tried using the following code "boxplot(raw.expression[1:50],log="xy",xlim=c(0.001,70),pch='.',col=rainbow(ncol(raw.expression[1:50])))"                               It igves me the following error:"In plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) :
  nonfinite axis limits [GScale(-inf,4.4591,2, .); log=1]" Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are plotting 400 boxes in your box plot, I am not surprised that you are having trouble seeing them. Suppose that you have a monitor that is 1024 pixels wide. Your application will only be able to display the boxes as two pixels wide. Even with larger screens you will not increase the number of pixels by much (a screen with 2000 pixels will at most show you boxes that are 5 pixels wide).

I would suggest plotting your boxes on two or more separate plots.